# A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

When I run `mvn clean install` on my maven project, It is giving me the below error

```
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ commons ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=6375, ConflictMarker.markTime=11066, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=2217, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=5579, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=36123, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=1, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=1274402, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=94657}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.2.0
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1:runtime
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:jar:3.2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.1
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4b85612c]
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugins.jar.JarMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/maven/archiver/MavenArchiveConfiguration;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields (Class.java:3061)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields (Class.java:2248)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredFields (InjectionPoint.java:760)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:670)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:378)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding (InjectorImpl.java:603)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:932)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields (Class.java:3061)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields (Class.java:2248)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredFields (InjectionPoint.java:760)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints (InjectionPoint.java:670)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields (InjectionPoint.java:378)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies (InjectorImpl.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup (InjectorImpl.java:617)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding (InjectorImpl.java:603)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:932)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive (InjectorImpl.java:852)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding (InjectorImpl.java:291)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:222)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow (InjectorImpl.java:1040)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1071)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider (InjectorImpl.java:1034)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  4.532 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-08-11T16:02:56+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) on project commons: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar: Lorg/apache/maven/archiver/MavenArchiveConfiguration;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/abdul/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/3.2.0/maven-jar-plugin-3.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/abdul/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiveConfiguration
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) on project commons: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar: Lorg/apache/maven/archiver/MavenArchiveConfiguration;
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/Users/abdul/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/3.2.0/maven-jar-plugin-3.2.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/Users/abdul/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar: Lorg/apache/maven/archiver/MavenArchiveConfiguration;
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/Users/abdul/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/3.2.0/maven-jar-plugin-3.2.0.jar
urls[1] = file:/Users/abdul/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
    

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) on project commons: Execution default-jar of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar: Lorg/apache/maven/archiver/MavenArchiveConfiguration;
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0
    [ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
    [ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/abdul/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/3.2.0/maven-jar-plugin-3.2.0.jar
    [ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/abdul/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
    [ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
    [ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
```

My `pom.xml` Have

```
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
   
    // dependencies section here

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

`mvn -v` output

```
Apache Maven 3.8.4
Maven home: /Users/abdul/apache-maven-3.8.4
Java version: 11.0.13, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Users/abdul/jdk-11.0.13.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "11.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

`java -version` output

```
java version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.13+10-LTS-370)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.13+10-LTS-370, mixed mode)
```

Comment: The output of `mvn -v` looks strange because on my system it starts with: `Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)` ...also the full log output of the whole build would be helpful...

Comment: This class is coming from the `maven-archiver` jar, which should be a dependency of the `maven-jar-plugin`. Can you check in the build log with debug enabled (`-X`) what the resolved dependency list of your jar plugin looks like?

Comment: I've added the build logs running the command with -X option

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the jars in your local `.m2` directory. Can you remove `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins` and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the maven build command with argument `-X` to enable debug logging.

Normally the class `MavenArchiveConfiguration` is loaded from `maven-archiver`, which is a dependency of the `maven-jar-plugin`. These dependencies are managed in the plugins' pom file, and loaded by the maven build process from that pom.

When i locally modify the pom file for this plugin (remove all `dependencies`) then i can reproduce this error message. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with your downloaded copy.

As a solution you can remove the contents of `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\` and `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-archiver` and try your build again, then all correct plugin files and dependencies should be downloaded again from maven central.

Then you should find the jar+pom files for the plugin + dependency in your local .m2 folder: `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-jar-plugin\3.2.0` and `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-archiver\3.5.0`. You can also look in those folders for the `_remote.repositories` file to check for any download issues.

You can also check if you have any custom `pluginRepositories` configured that may be providing you with corrupt jar/pom files. You can see your entire pom file by running `mvn help:effective-pom`.

Normally that should include the following from the [super pom](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.5/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html):

```xml
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

More extreme measures could be to download a newer version of maven, or clear your entire local `.m2` (create a backup if you have important files in there).

Those would be the places to look to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks @slindenau , deleting the local directory .m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\ worked.